# string mutation with accented letters in php code

Tags: php, arrays, string, non-ascii-characters

I have a string replacement that includes accented letters. I also used already a normalizer so that I have the same encoding and I cannot remove the diacritics because I need them for my output. My Code:

```
 $word = array("bā","ba");

for($i=0;$i<count($word);$i++)
{

    $accented = array("ā","ē","ī","ō","ū");

    $last = substr($word[$i],-1);


    if (    in_array($last,$accented)) { // replacement of the array with the accented letters
        $word[$i] = rtrim("x",$word[$i]);
    }



}
```

How can I modify my code so that it works for accented letters?

Comment: Ok. Whats is your question?

Comment: what is it in relation to? database insert or???

Comment: @FelippeDuarte post edited

Comment: Ok, but, what is not working?

Comment: @Hallur I do not understand your question. It is simply a code that does only not work because of the accented letters in `$accented`

Comment: Yes, I understand that... but why doesn't it work, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte There should be a replacement of the array element of `"bā"` by `x`. So at the end I should get `Array ( [0] => x [1] => bam )`

Answer (score 2):

Use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php):

```
$last = mb_substr($word[$i],-1);
```

It will work properly with accenteded letters.

Output will be

```
Array (
    [0] => x
    [1] => bam
)
```